# Objective-c mingw in windows

Tags: objective-c, windows, mingw

What tutorials cover how to use Objective-C in Windows?

I heard about mingw, but I couldn't configure it. I would like to only create command-line programs because I heard that there is no iPhone/iPad simulator for Windows and I would like to learn Objective-C.

Comment: This article about [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/experience/Windows.html) should help. [Compile Objective-C Programs Using gcc](http://blog.lyxite.com/2008/01/compile-objective-c-programs-using-gcc.html)