# Setting up Windows machine to write Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, windows-vista

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective C for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows)
>   [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

How do i setup and write Objective-C on my Windows Vista (32 bit) machine?

Can someone please give me instructions?

Comment: I have asked for `Objective-C` not `iPhone`, Please read the question or ask someone to explain it to you if you don't understand.

the thread you posted might have the answer, but the questions are different.

Comment: "iphone" seems to be one of the tags under this question.

Comment: i have removed it, and the question doesn't say anything about iPhone, but only about objective-C

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903869/is-it-possible-to-execute-objective-c-programs-in-windows or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144003/objective-c-mingw-in-windows or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326589/can-we-compile-objective-c-on-windows or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333196/objective-c-on-windows-and-gcc and especially http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394285/windows-development-using-objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GNUStep http://www.gnustep.org/. You can also use Eclipse CDT with GNUStep, see configuration here http://wirecode.blogspot.com/2007/11/objective-c-and-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to compile Objective C code on a Windows machine using the GNUStep toolchain.  But this will not allow you to write iPhone apps, as the Objective C runtimes are very different, so you won't be able to link with any of Apple's iOS frameworks, or use much of their example code.

Comment: Thank you, i am not going to develop `iPhone` apps, i only need to learn `Objective-C`